# Android Custom camera app Image Resolution issue

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am developing an android Custom Camera app without using the built-in intent. And I am using the Below code for Surface change

```
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sHolder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        if (isPreview)
        {
           try
           {
                camera.stopPreview();
                isPreview = false;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged", e);
           }
       }

       try
       {
              Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
              p.setPreviewSize(surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight());
              camera.setParameters(p);

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
             Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged", e);
       }


       try
       {
               camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
       } 
       catch (IOException e)
       {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
         camera.startPreview();
         isPreview = true;

     }
```

But After using the above code in my custom camera app, The image resolution is very low compared to built-in camera app though I am not setting any resolution explicitly in my code. Not getting where I am going wrong! Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `getSupportedPictureSizes()` on `Camera.Parameters` to find the size you want, or use that information to populate a ListView or Spinner

Check [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) out ...it will surely help you

Comment: I am able to find the SupportedPicture Sizes for a device. But while setting the picture size it is taking the lowest picture size resolution of that device. Can u please tel how to set the picture size to the Highest resolution available for that device?

Comment: Look at [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/08/determine-best-camera-preview-size.html) 
`getbestpreviewsize`